# Get PEBS data linear address from perf

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, perf

I'm now trying to using perf to measure L3_Miss(LLC Miss) with PEBS.

Here is the command: `perf record -d -e cpu/event=0xd1,umask=0x20/ppu -c 1 test`, and when the perf finished, I using `perf script -F ip,sym,addr` to check the result.

According to the [SDM from intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf), Vol. 3B Table 18-55. PEBS record contains a field named Data Linear Address, stands for address of load or destination of store, is what I need.

My question is, the field **addr** I specified in `perf-script` is same as **Data Linear Address** in PEBS record?
If not, how to retrieve this field? (and another related field such like CPU register R8~R15)

ps. I'm using i7-6700 CPU (Skylake Microarchitecture)

Thanks, and any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are right. The addr field in **perf script** does, in fact, give you the **data linear address** in a PEBS record. This data linear address is associated with the source of the load or the destination of the store, as you correctly specified. The switch **-d** that you used in your command `perf record -d` helps to record the linear addresses of the data accessed or written to in memory.

This mechanism to record **Data Linear Addresses** has started from the processor microarchitecture name **Haswell** replacing precise-store events. It has carried on to **Skylake** as well.

If you want to see this in code, [here you go](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/events/intel/ds.c#L1168).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it :) And I have another question.. when `perf record` finished, it shows `[ perf record: Captured and wrote 5.390 MB perf.data (44025 samples) ]`, but when I enter the `perf report`, it shows `# Samples: 16K of event 'cpu/event=0xd0,umask=0x81/ppu'  # Event count (approx.): 16649000`.  Why is the counter of same meaning has different value?

Comment: I know that PEBS generate a sample record every N events, and the numbers in the `perf report`: 16K samples / 16649000 events make sense (with `perf record -c 1000` flag). But 16K samples only generate 44025 samples in perf.data, this is illogical.

Comment: Hi @KanielVenson, can you please show me the exact perf command that you run ?

Comment: It will also be better if you raise this as a separate question and please set my answer to correct if it solves your question.