# How to obtain PEBS data linear address and latency value from the perf report?

Tags: linux, intel, perf

I am trying to use perf to obtain the value of PEBS data linear address and latency value using perf for the `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_RETIRED.L3_MISS` event (which I think is the LLC miss event). I have used the following command:

```
perf record -d -e cpu/event=0xd1,umask=0x20/ppu -F 1000 --intr-regs=SI,DI,BP,SP,R8 [application]
```

This generates the perf.data file. How can I read this file to obtain the data linear address and load latency value? I have tried using this command to dump the generated report in raw format and extract RECORD_SAMPLE from it:

```
perf report -D -i perf.data | grep RECORD_SAMPLE > sample.txt
```

I don't completely understand the columns it generates as there are no headers. I have attached few lines from the sample.txt file:

```
7248128953093548 0x16fa0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0xffffffff8163d9ac period: 15 addr: 0
7248128962085643 0x16ff8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 16 addr: 0
7248128972080714 0x17050 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b707db4 period: 16 addr: 0
7248128980080286 0x170a8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0xffffffff8163d9ac period: 16 addr: 0
7248128989072422 0x17100 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d6c8 period: 16 addr: 0
7248128998067923 0x17158 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b73a584 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129006067467 0x171b0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0xffffffff8163d9ac period: 16 addr: 0
7248129016059056 0x17208 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d574 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129024055215 0x17260 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b707d30 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129033051029 0x172b8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c4f period: 15 addr: 0
7248129041156459 0x17310 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0xffffffff8163d9ac period: 15 addr: 0
7248129050042391 0x17368 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d5af period: 16 addr: 0
7248129058038570 0x173c0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d582 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129070032626 0x17418 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d5a4 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129079028316 0x17470 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b707ebf period: 15 addr: 0
7248129088023771 0x174c8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b707e89 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129098019481 0x17520 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129105015588 0x17578 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d6d6 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129118009214 0x175d0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b739482 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129126005649 0x17628 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129133001958 0x17680 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129143996535 0x176d8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129151996795 0x17730 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0xffffffff8163d9ac period: 15 addr: 0
7248129163986760 0x17788 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 15 addr: 0
7248129173166957 0x177e0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b7455ed period: 15 addr: 0
7248129180978406 0x17838 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d589 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129188974446 0x17890 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c2f period: 16 addr: 0
7248129199968956 0x178e8 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c93 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129208964678 0x17940 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c23 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129217960457 0x17998 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b75c9dc period: 16 addr: 0
7248129227955422 0x179f0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d5b2 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129236950918 0x17a48 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x42d5b2 period: 16 addr: 0
7248129247945633 0x17aa0 [0x58]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4001): 129174/129174: 0x7fd38b756c05 period: 16 addr: 0
```

Also, the addr value is 0 which should not be the case. I have refered to several similar stackoverflow questions but none of them completely answer my question.

1. [Get PEBS data linear address from perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903459/get-pebs-data-linear-address-from-perf)
2. [perf-report show value of CPU register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163079/perf-report-show-value-of-cpu-register)

My processor is E5-2650 v3. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

*Note: I have asked the same question at Intel forum. Here is the link for that:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/805945
I should have just posted the link instead of posting the complete question again.

**Updated Output:**

```
7271806242314836 0x31ba8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd121170e7 period: 12136 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7d0
7271806243314179 0x31c10 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd121170e3 period: 12158 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7c0
7271806244321965 0x31c78 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d6c6 period: 12152 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e808
7271806245308373 0x31ce0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d572 period: 12162 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e80c
7271806246292832 0x31d48 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116eb4 period: 12202 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e805
7271806247289941 0x31db0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd121170e7 period: 12233 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7d0
7271806248306006 0x31e18 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12148467 period: 12210 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7d8
7271806249308119 0x31e80 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116d6c period: 12186 addr: 0x7fcd1249a0c8
7271806250308990 0x31ee8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c08 period: 12190 addr: 0x7fcd1249bcd4
7271806251307427 0x31f50 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd1216b9c5 period: 12191 addr: 0x7fcd137519b4
7271806252297279 0x31fb8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c2f period: 12202 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7f1
7271806253299296 0x32020 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d7c8 period: 12214 addr: 0x7ffc54f2f110
7271806254304888 0x32088 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd121494fc period: 12205 addr: 0x229c4f8
7271806255306048 0x320f0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd1216b99e period: 12200 addr: 0x7fcd13751941
7271806256289251 0x32158 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116eb4 period: 12217 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e806
7271806257293080 0x321c0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116ce0 period: 12234 addr: 0x7fcd12498dc0
7271806258301450 0x32228 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116d77 period: 12216 addr: 0x7fcd12246b23
7271806259297345 0x32290 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c93 period: 12217 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e80d
7271806260296250 0x322f8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd121170e5 period: 12229 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7c8
7271806261297185 0x32360 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d572 period: 12225 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e808
7271806262316489 0x323c8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165ca9 period: 12211 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e70c
7271806263329132 0x32430 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c8e period: 12158 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e709
7271806264337550 0x32498 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165ca9 period: 12131 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e711
7271806265349338 0x32500 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d572 period: 12110 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e808
7271806266359123 0x32568 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x42d7c8 period: 12076 addr: 0x7ffc54f2f110
7271806267338135 0x325d0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd1214838b period: 12090 addr: 0x229c4f0
7271806268335486 0x32638 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c8c period: 12124 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e804
7271806269327045 0x326a0 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165c9b period: 12145 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e809
7271806270315896 0x32708 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116eb4 period: 12162 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e807
7271806271319673 0x32770 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12165cd5 period: 12176 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e7d8
7271806272325312 0x327d8 [0x68]: PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE(IP, 0x4002): 130944/130944: 0x7fcd12116eb4 period: 12170 addr: 0x7ffc54f2e801
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem on a processor with the same microarchitecture. The commands you're using look fine to me.

Comment: I noticed you posted the same question on the Intel software tuning forum. You should not post the same question on more than one forum *at the same time*. Instead you should wait for 2-3 days before posting it on another forum so that you don't waste people's time who might try to answer your question.

Comment: @HadiBrais I didn't say I was getting any error except for addr value as 0 which I believe that it shouldn't be 0. My issue is that I don't know from the output of sample.txt file which is the data linear address and which is the load latency value or if the sample.txt even contains those values.

Comment: I apologize for asking the same question at two platforms. I wanted to catch the attention of wider audience as pebs and perf are not a very common topic. I had posted a question few months ago related to PAPI and didn't receive any answer hence in desperation I posted this question on two platforms. I will update the question and add the link of the one in the intel forum.

Comment: Right, there is no error, but I was saying that I have executed the same two commands and I do see valid `addr` values. But your trace looks suspicious though. First, if you are using `cpu/event=0xd1,umask=0x20/ppu` then how come there are IPs in the kernel address space? Did you produce that trace using a different command? It looks to me that the problem is that you forgot to append `ppu` to `cpu/event=0xd1,umask=0x20/`.

Comment: I think the question you are referring to is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467699/how-to-get-last-level-cache-miss-event-information-using-hardware-counters, right? Yeah the answer is to use PEBS. I don't know if PAPI supports PEBS though. But the [perf_event](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) API does support PEBS.

Comment: You are right, I did make a mistake. I have updated the output and now I do get addr. Also, I still get the IP so that shouldn't be a problem. Now can you tell how to get the data linear address and load latency from the perf.data file.

Comment: `addr` is the linear address. The latency is the L3 latency because you're sampling on the L3_MISS event. If you have a single socket, then you roughly estimate that to be equal to the average memory latency.

Comment: Based on the intel documentation (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325384-sdm-vol-3abcd.pdf), section 18.3.1.1.2  latency should be reported for retired demand load operations and in core cycles. I doubt it is the latency of L3 latency.

Comment: It looks like you have managed to obtain the linear address now. Is the question still open ?